# Use OS.File to test if path is locked?

Tags: firefox-addon

With `OS.File` I am able to open a file with lock on it:

```
let options = {
  winShare: 0 // Exclusive lock on Windows
};
if (OS.Constants.libc.O_EXLOCK) {
  // Exclusive lock on *nix
  options.unixFlags = OS.Constants.libc.O_EXLOCK;
}
let file = yield OS.File.open(..., options);
```

Is it possible to test if the path is locked though. I'm looking for alternative to `nsiToolkitProfile.lockProfile`

This is copy paste to scratchpad code. The top block uses `nsitoolkitprofile` to test if locked. And it works fine. The second part uses `OS.File.open` and it always throws error.

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm');
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm');
var tps = Cc['@mozilla.org/toolkit/profile-service;1'].createInstance(Ci.nsIToolkitProfileService); //toolkitProfileService

var folderOfProfile = 'k46wtieb.clean'; //folder names of relative profiles found here: %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles

var rootPathDefault = FileUtils.getFile('DefProfRt', []).path;
var localPathDefault = FileUtils.getFile('DefProfLRt', []).path;

var aDirect = new FileUtils.File(OS.Path.join(rootPathDefault, folderOfProfile));
var aTemp = new FileUtils.File(OS.Path.join(localPathDefault, folderOfProfile));
try {
    var locker = tps.lockProfilePath(aDirect, aTemp)
    Services.ww.activeWindow.alert('NOT open');
    locker.unlock();
} catch (ex) {
    if (ex.result == Cr.NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) {
        Services.ww.activeWindow.alert('its in use');
    } else {
        throw ex;
    }
}

var promise = OS.File.open(aDirect.path)
promise.then(
    function(aVal) {
        Services.ww.activeWindow.alert('promise success, aVal = ' + aVal);
        aVal.close();
    },
    function(aReason) {
        Services.ww.activeWindow.alert('promise rejected, aReason = ' + uneval(aReason));
    }
)
```

The promise is always rejected with `aReason.becauseAccessDenied` every time :(

Answer (score 1):

Just try to open it... If you cannot because of permissions, then the file is probably locked in another location.

Comment: whenever i open a folder though it is always rejected, please see my trials updated in question

Comment: oh i forgot to mention: The promise is always rejected with `aReason.becauseAccessDenied` every time regardless if its open or not

Comment: Hey @nmaier can you please comment on my upate :(

Comment: Update: This only works for windows. For Mac OS and Linux I had to use `fcntl`. For the Firefox profile lock if `fcntl` fails I have to use `readlink` to read their symbolic link lock protocol. Adapted from: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/profile/dirserviceprovider/src/nsProfileLock.cpp#289